# How to declare an object property with const

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I need to declare a variable for `formstate.title` from this:

```
    const initialState = { description: '', place: "", date: "", membersJoinedCounter: 0, title: ""  };
    
    const [formState, setFormState] = useState(initialState);

    function setInput(key, value,) {
        setFormState({ ...formState, [key]: value })
      }
    
    const userTitle = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getUserTitle, {id: userInfo.attributes.sub}))
    formState.title = userTitle.data.getUser.title;
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: I need formState.title to be variable so that the property updates everytime user updates Title, right now it doesn't update in the database

Comment: you are mutating the state. update value `formState` with `setFormState`.

Comment: "formState.title" is already variable. Do you "setState" the form state anywhere?

Comment: please check updated code

Answer (score 2):

it's not clear what you wanted to ask, but assuming you want to set title value after fetching data, you can achieve that via using setFormstate method provided by useState hook (you can't directly set values as formstate returned by useState hook is immutable)

replace below line in your code

`formState.title = userTitle.data.getUser.title`

with below one

`setFormState(prev=>({...prev,title:userTitle.data.getUser.title}))`

Comment: please check updated code, how can i add title property in setFormState? I need title to update everytime user changes title value

Comment: @Tony "setInput" does this already.

Comment: calling setInput function like setInput("title",userTitle.data.getUser.title) this will do the job